# Generators of cyclic group integers of infinity order

Tags: group-theory

Regarding the order of cyclic groups, we know that the set of integers with respect to addition operation is a group, but now I have a question:"Does this group have other generators except 1 and -1? "

Because the order of the cyclic group is infinity, so I can't even calculates the number of generators. So by using inspection, I found that there are no other generators except 1 and -1.

Is it correct?

Comment: You are right. Only -1 & 1 are two generators

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, the group generated by an integer  $g$ is  $ \langle g\rangle=\{ a \cdot z | z \in\mathbb{Z} \} $
If we suppose $ 1\in\langle g \rangle $ we get $g$ is either 1 or -1.